# Error messages when adding code to function.php or trying to delete inactive plugin files

Tags: errors, headers, wp-redirect

Error message below:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/79/7603579/html/listings/wp-content/themes/OIB theme/functions.php:519) in /home/content/79/7603579/html/listings/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897

EDIT: Code around `functions.php` line 519:

```
    <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div> 
    <?php break; 
case "section":
    $i++; ?>
    <div class="rm_section">
       <div class="rm_title">
         <h3><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/functions/images/trans.gif" class="inactive" alt="""><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
         <span class="submit">
            <input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
         </span>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rm_options">
    <?php break;
   } 
} ?>
```

And the fix, per comment below, removed this code:

```
function cpt_Search_category_Filter($query) {
   $post_type = array('post','business_sold');
   if ($query->is_search || $query->is_category) {
      $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
   };
      return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts','cpt_Search_category_Filter');
```

Comment: Can you show the code around line 519 of your `functions.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `functions.php` file is outputting instead of returning something, on line 519.

Can you post whatever code/functions are around Line 519?

EDIT:

You have a *syntax error* in your `cpt_Search_category_Filter()` function. You have a couple stray semi-colons after closing braces.

Change this:

```
function cpt_Search_category_Filter($query) {
   $post_type = array('post','business_sold');
   if ($query->is_search || $query->is_category) {
      $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
   };
      return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts','cpt_Search_category_Filter');
```

to this:

```
function cpt_Search_category_Filter($query) {
   $post_type = array('post','business_sold');
   if ($query->is_search || $query->is_category) {
      $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
   }
      return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','cpt_Search_category_Filter');
```

Comment: Hello!  Now it's apparently causing login errors as well - here is the code around line 531:

Comment: <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small><div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
<?php break; 
case "section":

$i++;

?>

<div class="rm_section">
<div class="rm_title"><h3><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/functions/images/trans.gif" class="inactive" alt="""><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3><span class="submit"><input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
</span><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="rm_options">

 
<?php break;
 
}
}
?>

Comment: I apologize - the code I posted isn't formatted.  I'm still scrambling to find a way to reasonably post code here.  I'll keep working on it.  I so appreciate your effort to help me.

Comment: Hello again~  This following fix added to function.php is apparently what was causing the error in function.php.  I removed so now the system is not recognizing the assignment of the inherent/default (per plugin Custom Post UI) taxonomony of 'categories' (and tags) to my custom post type.  The plugin does not assign. function cpt_Search_category_Filter($query) {    $post_type = array('post','business_sold');    if ($query->is_search || $query->is_category) {        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);    };    return $query;};add_filter('pre_get_posts','cpt_Search_category_Filter');

Comment: The best approach would probably be to edit your original question, and post the code there. :)

Comment: @chip - she is too new to edit her post. But you my friend have racked up more than enough reputation to do it for her. We started about the same time. 15x the rep as me!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I totally appreciate the forum I'm particpating in and hope, someday, to show you that I can contribute as well as glean insight.  I hope you understand that I am scrambling and should have had a better workflow, but I will do better with the next project~  You've saved my deadline on this one!