# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (wp_redirect in functions.php)

Tags: functions, wp-redirect

I already consulted [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/error-messages-when-adding-code-to-function-php-or-trying-to-delete-inactive-plu?s=1%7C132.3108) and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179070/wp-redirect-headers-already-sent) but did not see a solution.

I need to redirect a page based on its `$post->post_type` and from what little I know, I can get this information inside the `template_redirect` hook.

So I have code below inside `functions.php` (of astra-child theme):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redir_sorteio'); 

function redir_sorteio() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'sorteio') 
        wp_redirect('/edicao/?id=' . $post->ID);
}
```

**And it works perfectly.**

But for some reason, errors have appeared within the log, like:

```
[18-May-2018 01:11:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rogeriod/public_html/wordpress/sortemania/wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php:32) in /home/rogeriod/public_html/wordpress/sortemania/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1311
```

Where line 32 of functions.php (above) is the `wp_redirect('/edicao/?id=' . $post->ID)` and line 1311 of wordpress functions.php is the `header` command inside `do_robots`function:

```
function do_robots() {
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
```

How can I find out what causes this and resolve it, since `wp_redirect` is working and no error appears directly to the user?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but good practice: **Always `exit;` after `wp_redirect()`.** [See the note in the **Description** section in the documentation.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) (This is true whether you use `wp_redirect()` or `wp_safe_redirect()`.)

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing wp_redirect with wp_safe_redirect and if you have php closing tag "?>" at end of files, remove them, at least you can check the header.php for php closing tag.

Comment: I'll try and wait to see if I get no more errors, and then accept you answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answers to change to `wp_safe_redirect` and put `exit();` at the end, partially resolved the problem and it is a solution that only works inside the `template_redirect`, because in other places the problem persists.

This became a nightmare and I realized that it is also the nightmare of many, until I was able to find in a post an efficient, albeit unorthodox, solution: **javascript**.

So, after several attempts and errors, I got a stable code like this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redireciona_sorteio'); 

function redireciona_sorteio() {
    global $post;
    if (isset($post->post_type)) {
        if ($post->post_type == 'sorteio') {
            if (!$post->ID) {
                echo '<script> location.replace("/"); </script>';
            }
            else {
                wp_safe_redirect('/edicao/?id=' . $post->ID);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```